# Bash remote files system directory test

Tags: bash, ssh

the more I learn bash the more questions I have, and the more I understand why very few people do bash. Easy is something else, but I like it.

I have managed to figure out how to test directories and there writablity, but have a problem the minute I try to do this with a remote server over ssh. The first instance testing the /tmp directory works fine, but when the second part is called, I get `line 0: [: missing`]'`

**Now if I replace the \" with a single quote, it works, but I thought that single quotes turn of variable referencing ??** Can someone explain this to me please ? Assuming that the tmp directory does exist and is writable, here the script so far

```
#!/bin/bash
SshHost="hostname"
SshRsa="~/.ssh/id_rsa"
SshUser="user"
SshPort="22"
Base="/tmp"
Sub="one space/another space"

BaseBashExist="bash -c \"[ -d \"$Base\" ] && echo 0 && exit 0 || echo 1 && exit 1\""
SSHBaseExist=$( ssh -l $SshUser -i $SshRsa -p $SshPort $SshHost ${BaseBashExist} )
echo -n $Base
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo -n "...OK..."
    else
        echo "...FAIL"
        exit 1
fi
BaseBashPerm="bash -c \"[ -w \"$Base\" ] && echo 0 && exit 0 || echo 1 && exit 1\""
SSHBaseExist=$( ssh -l $SshUser -i $SshRsa -p $SshPort $SshHost ${BaseBashPerm} )
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "...writeable"
    else
        echo "...not writeable"
fi

BaseAndSub="$Base/$Sub"
BaseAndSubBashExist="bash -c \"[ -d \"$BaseAndSub\" ] && echo 0 && exit 0 || echo 1 && exit 1\""
SSHBaseAndSubExist=$( ssh -l $SshUser -i $SshRsa -p $SshPort $SshHost ${BaseAndSubBashExist} )
echo -n $BaseAndSub
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo -n "...OK..."
    else
        echo "...FAIL"
        exit 1
fi
BaseAndSubBashPerm="bash -c \"[ -w \"$BaseAndSub\" ] && echo 0 && exit 0 || echo 1 && exit 1\""
SSHBaseAndSubPerm=$(  ssh -l $SshUser -i $SshRsa -p $SshPort $SshHost ${BaseAndSubBashPerm} )
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo -n "...writeable"
    else
        echo "...not writeable"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: What do you mean "very few people do it"?  Granted, few people do it really well, but that's another topic altogether.

Comment: No offence intended, just that in the 15 years of development I have really only a hand full of people that actually know bash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fine with single quotes in this context; by the time the script is seen by the remote bash, your local bash has already substituted in the variables you want to substitute.

However, your script is a total mess.  You should put the repetitive code in functions if you cannot drastically simplify it.

```
#!/bin/bash

remote () {
    # most of the parameters here are at their default values;
    # why do you feel you need to specify them?
    #ssh -l "user" -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 22 hostname "$@"
    ssh hostname "$@"
    # —---------^
    # if you really actually need to wrap the remote
    # commands in bash -c "..." then add that here
}

exists_and_writable () {
    echo -n "$1"

    if remote test -d "$1"; then
        echo -n "...OK..."
    else
        echo "...FAIL"
        exit 1
    fi

    if remote test -w "$1"; then
        echo "...writeable"
    else
        echo "...not writeable"
    fi
}

Base="/tmp"
# Note the need for additional quoting here
Sub="one\\ space/another\\ space"

exists_and_writable "$Base"

BaseAndSub="$Base/$Sub"

exist_and_writable "$BaseAndSub"

exit 0
```

Comment: adding a function for the files tests saves almost 35% of code and it still is simple.

Comment: Note also how the exit code from `ssh` is the exit code from the remote command. The whole `&& echo 0 || echo 1` thing you had was superfluous.

Comment: the reason for the echo was so that I have a local variable to test after the fact. This would allow me to do a global test after preforming multiple directory test.. if that makes any sense, but with your approache this local variable testing is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is refactor your code with simplicity in mind, then the quoting error will go away as well. Try:

```
if ssh [flags] test -w "'$file'"; then
```

Encapsulate your SSH flags in a ssh config to facilitate re-use, and your script will shorten dramatically.

Comment: +1 and ditto for the remote `bash -c "command"` invocations.  There might be situations where you genuinely need to run Bash instead of your regular login shell on the remote host, but I strongly speculate that this is not one of those cases.

Comment: encapsulating the flags and simply double quoting the `$file` does save about 20% of code and greatly simplifies the structure... Thanks for the input. **Can I assume then that single quotes inside double quotes does not prevent variable referencing**, contrary to what the documentation says.. ?

Comment: Try `echo "foo '$HOME'"` and think about it for a while. The single quotes are not special inside double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
ssh -qnx "useraccount@hostname" 
     "test -f ${file absolute path} ||
      echo ${file absolute path} no such file or directory"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).